# Mysql database frequently getting locked

Tags: php, mysql

I have executed a complex query to display a report in the website. The query got locked. This cause deadlock since there were other users and process running in the website. I have killed all the queries. I havent ran the query which caused the issue again.
But still other queries are getting locked now. They were not supposed to.

Comment: Please show your query which is going to locked?

Comment: run the explain on your report query and share the information into the question  `explain select ...`

Comment: The query is a very long one with multiple joins. I am not getting results for explain too now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with MySQL that they do not acknowledge.

You just need to use

```
UNLOCK TABLES
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: It does not work. Locked tables are still seems as lock. I used the query SHOW OPEN TABLES; to see the locked tables

Comment: When I kill the queries, it is fine. But after few minutes queries are again locked even if I did not run the problem query.

Comment: It did not work? Not a lot of help I can give here then.